# Highlight DataPoint in mschart on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

When the user clicks a particular `DataPoint` in the chart, i would like that DataPoint to be highlighted with a different color until the user clicks another DataPoint.
Is this possible in mschart?

Answer (score 7):

You have to subscribe to the mouseDown event and then call the HitTest method. Finally you can change the color of the DataPoint.

```
private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Call Hit Test Method
    HitTestResult result = Chart1.HitTest( e.X, e.Y );    
    if( result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint )
    {  
        Chart1.Series[0].Points[result.PointIndex].Color = Color.Green; 
        // reset the previous point selected here     
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ranjit Did this help you at all? Some feedback would be greatly appreciated.